# Lua get data from json array with cURL

Tags: json, curl, lua

I need to make a get request and retrieve data from a json array, but I don't know how to fetch a specific array index and print its value. There doesn't seem to be any information online about it either.

```
local curl = require("lcurl")

c = curl.easy{
    url = 'http://example.com/api/?key=1234',
    httpheader = {
      "Content-Type: application/json";
    };
    writefunction = io.stderr
  }
  c:perform()
c:close()
```

This returns

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "admin"
    }
]
```

But how can I make it print only the value of `name`?

Comment: Do you found a solution for your task?

Answer (score 1):

You can use some JSON library, for example, [this one](https://github.com/Egor-Skriptunoff/json4lua).

```
local json = require'json'

local function callback(path, json_type, value, pos, pos_last)
   local elem_path = table.concat(path, '/')  -- element's path
   --print(elem_path, json_type, value, pos, pos_last)
   if elem_path == "1/name" then  -- if current element corresponds to JSON[1].name
      print(value)
   end
end

local JSON_string = [[

[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "admin"
    }
]

]]

json.traverse(JSON_string, callback)
```

Output:

```
admin
```

---

Another solution (more simple, with full decoding of JSON):

```
local json = require'json'

local JSON_string = [[

[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "admin"
    }
]

]]

print(json.decode(JSON_string)[1].name)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. What I don't get though is how I'd store the data from curl in a variable, as in `c:perform()` prints everything to the console but there doesn't seem to be an option to store that data into a variable?

Comment: @P.Nick - probably, `c:setopt_writefunction(...)` may help.

Comment: Easy way `t={} c:setopt_writefunction(table.insert, t)` And after perform do `str = table.concat(t)`

Comment: Please answer specifically to what OP requested (which is how to get from URL). I don't see any related URL in the code.